# Regex for asp.net routing in multiple languages

Tags: asp.net, regex, unicode, routes, multilingual

I need to write regex which I will use for asp.net routing constraint which should match any word. The problem is that words could be written in any language, for example

1. test
2. some-other-test
3. one-more-трудно-получить-result

Thx for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to match a url that has a word in it and pass that to your route, but the word could be in multiple languages.

By default an Asp.net MVC Route will work with any language. For example a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } 
            );
```

Will match a url like "/controller/action/one-more-трудно-получить-result". The ID parameter will hold the value "one-more-трудно-получить-result".

If you are looking to limit the route so it only matches words (no numbers) from any language then here is your regex:

```
[\p{L}\p{M}-]+
```

And here is how you would route this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "default" },
            new { id = @"[\p{L}\p{M}-]+" }
        );
```

The \p{L} will match any kind of letter from any language. The \p{M} will match any character intended to be combined with another character (e.g. accents, umlauts, enclosing boxes, etc.). This route will match a url like "/controller/action/one-more-трудно-получить-result" but not "/controller/action/one-more-трудно-по12341лучить-result".

Just an FYI the \p{N} is used to match any number, \p{P} is for punctuation, and \p{C} if for invisible control characters and unused code points.

Resources: 
http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html